# Get count of series/groups based on 14 days of interval

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I have a table containing range table like this.

```
+---------+---------+
| user_id | view_dt |
+---------+---------+
| A       |     1/1 |
+---------+---------+
| A       |    1/10 |
+---------+---------+
| A       |    1/14 |
+---------+---------+
| A       |    1/22 |
+---------+---------+
| A       |    1/23 |
+---------+---------+
| A       |    1/30 |
+---------+---------+
```

I want this data to be grouped based on a 14 day interval. That is, the groups would be:

GROUP 1: 1/1, 1/10, 1/14

GROUP 2： 1/22, 1/23, 1/30

Basically I want to count the orders by interval. So Output should be:

```
user_id: A          count of series = 2
```

Note that I the 1/30 date should belong to GROUP 2 since 1/30 should be compared to the first date of GROUP 2 (1/22) instead of (1/1).

I think it can be achieved by creating a recursive query because my grouping condition is 14 days from the first date of the group. Just curious if there's an alternative solution to the recursive CTE method?

Comment: Please always disclose your version of Postgres and a basic table definition - a `CREATE TABLE` statement showing data types and constraints. Is this for a *single* `user_id` or is the sample misleading?

Answer (score 2):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE 
cte1 AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt) rn,
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt 
                          RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND INTERVAL '15 day' FOLLOWING) cnt
    FROM test
    ORDER BY 1,2
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM cte1 
    WHERE rn = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cte1.*
    FROM cte1
    JOIN cte2 ON cte1.id = cte2.id
             AND cte1.rn = cte2.rn + cte2.cnt
)
SELECT id, COUNT(*)
FROM cte2
GROUP BY id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=874ecc698183349114594e6f01ece3fd

Comment: I like the clever trick to count rows within time range, and skip ahead in the recursive part. Should be `AND INTERVAL '14 day' FOLLOWING`, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the rare cases where a procedural solution might be faster because it can make do with a single scan over the table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION island_count(_days int = 14)
  RETURNS TABLE (user_id text, islands int)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   this_id text;  -- using user_id for "last_id" directly
   this_dt date;
   last_dt date;
BEGIN   
   FOR this_id, this_dt IN
      SELECT t.user_id, t.view_dt
      FROM   tbl t
      ORDER  BY 1, 2
   LOOP
      IF this_id = user_id THEN
         IF this_dt > last_dt + _days THEN
            islands := islands + 1;
            last_dt := this_dt;  -- restart frame
            -- RAISE NOTICE 'New island: user: % date: %', this_id, this_dt;  -- to debug
         END IF;
      ELSE
         IF user_id IS NULL THEN
            -- nothing to return yet
         ELSE
            RETURN NEXT;
         END IF;
         user_id := this_id;
         islands := 1;           -- restart count
         last_dt := this_dt;     -- restart frame
      END IF;
      -- else do nothing
   END LOOP;

   IF FOUND THEN                 -- if any rows at all ...
      RETURN NEXT;               -- ... terminate final loop
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM island_count();
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=86fba70d0a4f254780b44227a776f2aa)*

An index over `(user_id, t.view_dt)` will help performance *a lot* for big tables.

If you don't want to persist the function in the db, consider a "temporary function". See:

- [How to create temporary function in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4990622/939860)